# Bluetooth not working on Dell Latitude E6540 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, dell

I mis-configured something and can't sort it out. Wireless is working.
I have Blueman-applet installed and when I click "Turn Bluetooth ON", it shows it's turned on, but I can't see the laptop as discoverable device nor can discover other devices in the neighborhood.

dmesg | grep Blue:

```
[  626.322287] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[  626.322522] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  626.322529] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  626.322530] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  626.322534] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  626.329784] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  626.329787] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  626.329792] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  626.332064] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  626.332073] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  626.332077] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

rfkill list:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64d0 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please help identifying and resolving the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it has bluetooth?  If it did have bluetooth I would expect a hci0 device in the `rfkill list` results

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes it has, and it was working in the past and I used it to connect bluetooth headsets and my mobile phone. I mis-configured something when I went after a problem with wireless.

Comment: Check BIOS settings to see if bluetooth can be enabled there